# Convert Datetime String to Datetime in Original Timezone

Tags: c#

I have a timestamp in the format:

```
20110316 11:03:22.276919 -0400s
```

As an aside, does anyone know what the 's' is at the end of this datetime?

I am trying to convert this to a datetime object in the timezone it originally came from.  However performing the following conversion:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(source, "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.FFFFFF zzzz\\s", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Automatically converts it to my local timezone.

What I expect is a time of 11:03am in my datetime, however since I am in a timezone 2 hours behind the one in this timestamp, the conversion is returning 9:03am.  Other than performing a string truncation to ignore the timezone, is there a way to parse the date while keeping it in the timezone it came from?

Comment: Regarding the `s` at the end, can you tell us what system created the timestamp? I'm wondering if it is intended to show daylight savings time, is just some character the programmer felt like using to indicate the end, or is just a spurious character.

Comment: It's from a trading system called Fidessa.  I had not considered the daylight savings angle, I will explore that.  Thank you Andrew.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use DateTimeOffset

```
DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("20110316 11:03:22.276919 -0400s", @"yyyyMMdd HH\:mm\:ss\.FFFFFF zzz\s", null);
Console.WriteLine(dto.DateTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the CultureInfo in the conversion where exact it came from.

ex. `//if its from US then cultureInfo is like
CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime.ParseExact(source, "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.FFFFFF zzzz\\s", us)`

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  Culture info has to do with languages not timezones.  You can speak English-US anywhere in the world (your laptop doesn't care), but your timezone will be different.  My question asks, given where you are in the world, what time was it in the timezone of this Timestamp.