# Datetime conversion with milliseconds and timezone

Tags: c#, datetime

I found many questions about parsing datetime from various formats, but not able to find the solution to my problem of converting datetime string with milliseconds and timezone both.

My input is like

> 20110713014230.685+0000

And format of this is like:

> yyyyMMddHHmmss.fff+zzzz

I tried DateTime.ParseExact and DateTimeOffset.ParseExact with/without `+` and `.` but nothing worked.

Found similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542524/convert-datetime-string-to-datetime-in-original-timezone) but it's not working for me.

I get the exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "it's not working for me" means? Are you getting  an error?

Comment: @Adrian added the exception message in question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the format to `yyyyMMddHHmmss.fffzzzzz`, acording [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_41), the "zzz" custom format specifier represents the signed offset of the local operating system's time zone.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and accurate reply. I tried many combinations but not this one. Thanks once again.

Comment: Five "z"s? I see two or three "z"s.. what's 5 "z"s?

Comment: Yes, I used 4 z not 5. Just ignored it as a typo :)

Comment: But 4 "z"s is not a custom format specifier. You can use 1, 2 or 3, but not 4 or 5...

Comment: Here zzzz is for timezone which is in format of HH:mm, so first two zz are for hours and last one is for minutes.

Comment: The actual possible time stamp is in the format of : `YYYY[MM[DD[HH[MM[SS[.SSSS]]]]]][+/-ZZZZ]` . The one I mentioned in question is just one possible value.

Comment: Weird; although it works, [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#zzzSpecifier) disagrees. It explicitly describes "zzz" as the solution you want (and it works), but it doesn't mention "zzzz" at all. I've tested using your examples, and there is no difference between "zzz" and "zzzz" in your case. Very interesting!

Comment: Oh right, I tried with zzz too, its working same as with zzzz. I am changing it to triple z instead of 4; to match with documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime date;

var dateString = "20110713014230.685+0000";

dateString = dateString.Substring(0, 21) + ':' + dateString.Substring(21, 2);

DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMddHHmmss.fffzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
```

Comment: That might solve the issue, but involves lots of string operations which will results in processing cost.

Answer (score 0):

With dateTimeString = 20110713014230.685+0000 the following code should get you what you want:

```
if (!DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(dateTimeString, 
                                  "yyyyMMddHHmmss.fffzzz",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                   DateTimeStyles.None, 
                                   out var dateTimeWithOffset)){}
```

**Here's the intermediate output of the dateTimeWithOffset var:**

```
{7/13/2011 1:42:30 AM +00:00}
ClockDateTime: {7/13/2011 1:42:30 AM}
Date: {7/13/2011 12:00:00 AM}
DateTime: {7/13/2011 1:42:30 AM}
Day: 13
DayOfWeek: Wednesday
DayOfYear: 194
Hour: 1
LocalDateTime: {7/12/2011 9:42:30 PM}
Millisecond: 685
Minute: 42
Month: 7
Offset: {00:00:00}
Second: 30
Ticks: 634461181506850000
TimeOfDay: {01:42:30.6850000}
UtcDateTime: {7/13/2011 1:42:30 AM}
UtcTicks: 634461181506850000
Year: 2011
_dateTime: {7/13/2011 1:42:30 AM}
_offsetMinutes: 0
```